# How to store bigquery merge output into another table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, merge, google-bigquery

Is there any way to store the output of [BigQuery merge](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax) in a new data table? If not, is it possible to view the results somewhere in `GCP`? I don't want to modify the target table.

This is the query I'm using-

```
MERGE dataset.target T
USING dataset.source S
ON T.c1 = S.c1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
  DELETE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the rows deleted, you can copy `dataset.target` into `dataset.target2`, then execute your `MERGE` on `dataset.target`, then see the difference between `dataset.target2` and `dataset.target`:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.target2
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM dataset.target
```

Comment: I can not modify target dataset. That's the problem.